# Using Crypto-JS (commonjs) in titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, commonjs, cryptojs

I am not familiar with commonjs conception, so my strategy might be basically wrong..

I want to use CryptoJS.HMAC() and CryptoJS.SHA256 in titanium

I have downloaded CryptoJS v3.1.2.zip from [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/downloads).

then copy all files under Resources/CryptJS/ .

then I add this last line in core.js

```
    return C;
}(Math));

module.export = CryptoJS;  //add this line
```

now in my app.js

```
var CryptoJS = require('./CryptoJS/components/core');

CryptoJS.HMAC(CryptoJS.SHA256, dateStamp,  testKey, { asBytes: true});
```

however it shows

`undefined is not a function`  error when I call CryptoJS.HMAC()

Can I have help?

Answer (score 0):

You find a commonJS version of Crypto Js on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-cryptojs

Maybe you got more luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `s` to `export`, so it becomes:

```
module.exports = CryptoJS;  //add this line
```